# Create Jira issue from Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, jira, jenkins-agent

**Hi, I am trying to create a Jira issue through Jenkins on a Windows agent. The console output is not showing any error, however, the Jira issue is not getting created. Below is the code:**

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'windows'}
   stages {
    stage('Build') {
     steps {  
       bat script {"""curl -u ${jira_username}:${jira_password} -X POST -H 'Content- Type:application/json' -d '{"fields":{"components":[{"id":"1"}],"fixVersions":[{"id":"2"}],"project":{"key":"KEY"},"summary":"summary","description":"description","issuetype":{"name":"Test"}}}' http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/"""}
    }
  }
}
```

}

**The console output is:**

```
 D:\workspace\TestJob>curl -u username:password -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d 
'{"fields":{"components":[{"id":"1"}],"fixVersions":[{"id":"2"}],"project": 
{"key":"KEY"},"summary":"summary","description":"description","issuetype":{"name":"Test"}}}' 
http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/ 
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 100   136    0     0  100   136      0    323 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   326
```

**It doesn't throw any errors but the issue is also not getting created.**

**However, The same code if I run on Linux slave then I get the below response and the issue is getting created.**

```
  + curl -u 'username:password' -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -d '{"fields": 
  {"components":[{"id":"1"}],"fixVersions":[{"id":"2"}],"project": 
  {"key":"KEY"},"summary":"summary","description":"description","issuetype": 
  {"name":"Test"}}}' http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 100   255    0    87  100   168    115    223 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   223
 100   255    0    87  100   168    115    223 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   223
 {"id":"648","key":"KEY-35","self":"http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/648"}
```

**As you can see the issue is getting created on Linux but not on windows. Requesting help to resolve this issue.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved the issue**

Firstly **'Content-Type: application/json'** should be in double-quotes.
Putting it in single quote **'Content-Type: application/json'** was actually giving **415** error code which I got to know after using **-k -D-** in the curl command

Secondly, I had to use double backslash in the data.

**The command which actually worked is:**

```
bat script {"""curl -u username:password --header "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data "{\\"fields\\":{\\"project\\":{\\"key\\":\\"KEY\\"},\\"summary\\":\\"summary\\",\\"description\\":\\"description\\",\\"issuetype\\":{\\"name\\":\\"Test\\"},\\"components\\":[{\\"id\\":\\"1\\"}],\\"fixVersions\\":[{\\"id\\":\\"2\\"}]}}" http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/"""}
```